# GroupBy dataframe column without aggregation and set not null values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe having records like below:

```
+---+----+----+
|id |L1  |L2  |
+---+----+----+
|101|202 |null|
|101|null|303 |
+---+----+----+
```

Is their a simple way to groupBy and get result like below in Spark SQL:

```
+---+----+----+
|id |L1  |L2  |
+---+----+----+
|101|202 |303 |
+---+----+----+
```

Thanks.

Comment: Should L1 and L2 be a collection or.. What if there is another value with the same id besides 'null'?

Comment: what is your effort on the coding part where you are failing and need the help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max` or `min` to aggregate the data. Since you only have a single valid value, this is the one that will be selected. Note that it's not possible to use `first` here (which is faster) since that can still return null values.

When the columns are of numeric types it can be solved as follows:

```scala
df.groupBy("id").agg(max($"L1").as("L1"), max($"L2").as("L2"))
```

However, if you are dealing with strings, you need to collect all values as a list (or set) and then use `coalesce`:

```scala
df.groupBy("id")
  .agg(coalesce(collect_list($"L1")).as("L1"), coalesce(collect_list($"L2")).as("L2"))
```

Of course, this assumes that the nulls are not strings but actual nulls.

Comment: I tried this but getting everything null. I think the values are String and not Integer, so max function is not working here.

Comment: @AB: I see, I added an alternative that works for strings to the answer.